# Is it possible to open the Spotfire script window without navigating through a button?

Tags: spotfire

To open scripts in a given dxp I have to right click a button, select Edit Control, then I can create or edit scripts. I'm wondering if I can do this without going through a button?

Answer (score 2):

from the main menu bar, Edit...Document Properties...Scripts (tab)

Comment: Still feel kind of a workaround. It would be nice if I could just Edit > Scripts. Ah well.